# Using Omniture tagging with the jcycle plug-in

Tags: jquery, adobe-analytics, jcycle

Has anyone ever done omniture tagging with the jcycle plug-in? What I need to do is have the onmiture tags know what item was clicked without having a page refresh. So, if you were using the jcycle plugin, and you have a pager parameter, the omniture tag would need to know what page you visited, but still keep the jcycle horizontal scroll feature and no page refresh. Hopefully this makes sense. I don't think this is possible, but just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used this plugin, I can tell you that with Omniture Sitecatalyst there are are various ways of adding tracking behaviours to javascript events/actions.
e.g. add a function like the ones below to an onclick event.

The first function (lead) is an example of one that sets various variables/events on a click (but doesn't issue a new pageview).

The second function (pageview) implements a "virtual pageview" which will imitatate travelling through different pages as one clicks on things (even though there isn't an actual page load in reality).

```
function lead(type) {
    var s=s_gi(s_account);
    s.linkTrackVars="eVar25,eVar27,events";
    s.linkTrackEvents="event11,event12";
    s.events="event11,event12";
    s.eVar25=type;
    s.eVar27=type;
    s.tl(this,'o','interactions');
}

function pageview(pagename) {
    s.pageName=pagename;    
    void(s.t());
}
```